# Why does the antiderivative does not exist?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Okay so consider computing where $I = (-2,2)$

$$\int_Ix^{-2}dx$$ and $0 \in I$.

Here we can see that $x^{-2}$ is not defined at $x=0$, thus we can't compute the antiderivative and find the integrand, right?

But how come we can compute the antiderivative and find the integrand directly in the case below :

$$\int_Tx^{-1},$$ where $T=(0,2)$.

What's the difference? I don't get it.

Comment: The limits are open intervals right?

Comment: In the second case the function is well behaved in $T$ since it does not include 0. Or I fail to understand the problem...

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 2):

Annotating your post seems the easiest way to address everything.

> [...] consider computing
>   $$
> \int_{-2}^{2} x^{-2}\, dx\quad [....]
> \tag{1}
> $$
>   Here we can see that $x^{-2}$ is not defined at $x=0$,[**1**] thus we can't compute the antiderivative and find the integrand, right?[**2**]
>
> But how come we can compute the antiderivative and find the [integral][**3**] directly [for]
>   $$
> \int_{0}^{2} x^{-1}\, dx.
> \tag{2}
> $$
>   What's the difference?[**4**] I don't get it.

1. To nitpick, the problem isn't that $f(x) = x^{-2} = 1/x^{2}$ is *undefined* at $0$, it's that $f$ is *unbounded in every deleted neighborhood of $0$*. This fact alone does not mean the integral is "undefinable", it just means:

   (a) The (proper) Riemann integral is undefined (Riemann integrability assumes boundedness).

   (b) If there is any hope of defining (1) as an *improper* integral, it's by breaking up the integral at $0$ and determining whether the limits
   $$
   \lim_{b \to 0^{-}} \int_{-2}^{b} x^{-2}\, dx,\qquad
   \lim_{a \to 0^{+}} \int_{a}^{2} x^{-2}\, dx
   $$
   exist separately.
2. Sort of. The function $f(x) = x^{-2}$ *does* have antiderivatives on its domain, namely functions
   $$
   F(x) = \begin{cases}
     C_{1} - x^{-1} & x < 0, \\
     C_{2} - x^{-1} & x > 0.
   \end{cases}
   $$
   The domain is not an interval, and every antiderivative is unbounded near $0$, however, so there's no guarantee the fundamental theorem of calculus,
   $$
   \int_{-2}^{2} f(x)\, dx = F(2) - F(-2),
   $$
   applies. As you may have noticed, formal (careless) application of the FTC gives
   $$
   \int_{-2}^{2} x^{-2}\, dx = -x^{-1} \Big|_{-2}^{2} = -1.
   $$
   This conclusion looks paradoxical because the integrand is everywhere positive, but is unjustified because the hypotheses of the FTC don't hold, see item 4 below.

   Incidentally, if the integral (1) is split up, the "correct" value $\infty$ is obtained:
   \begin{align*}
     \lim_{b \to 0^{-}} \int_{-2}^{b} x^{-2}\, dx
     &= \lim_{b \to 0^{-}} -\frac{1}{b} + \frac{1}{2} = \infty, \\
     \lim_{a \to 0^{+}} \int_{a}^{2} x^{-2}\, dx
     &= \lim_{a \to 0^{+}} -\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{a} = \infty.
   \end{align*}
3. The integral (2) is also improper. Unlike (1), however, the integrand in (2) is only unbounded near one endpoint, so there is no need to split the interval of integration. The improper integral
   $$
   \lim_{a \to 0^{+}} \int_{a}^{2} x^{-1}\, dx = \lim_{a \to 0^{+}} \ln(2) - \ln(a) = \infty
   $$
   diverges, but unlike with (1), there is no indeterminacy. Formally, the evaluation "gives the correct area", namely infinity.
4. The difference is, the antiderivative in (2) is defined throughout the (open) interval of integration (so the FTC applies on $[a, 2]$ for each $a > 0$), while in (1) the antiderivative has an unbounded singularity *in the interior of the interval of integration*.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of as a side note, in complex analysis, we change the path slightly so that we go around $x=0$ on one side and take the limit as this loop closes in on $x=0$.

In the context of real analysis, we would usually handle this differently.  For example, we'd take the limit as the bounds approached $x=0:$

$$\lim_{\epsilon_1\to0^+}\int_{-2}^{-\epsilon_1}x^{-2}\ dx+\lim_{\epsilon_2\to0^+}\int_{\epsilon_2}^2x^{-2}\ dx$$

In both cases above, you'll find that the integrals do not exist since each separate limit diverges.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is not that the antiderivate doesn't exist, it's that the integrals are **improper** integrals because the integrand has a pole within the domain of integration (or on its boundary).

This is handled as @SimpleArt suggests, by backing off from the problematic point to give perfectly valid integrals, and then trying to find the limiting values as the "padding" shrinks to zero.